# check if a file having a given template exists

Tags: python

I need to perform a loop in order to check during time if files having a given template are added into a directory.

In pseudo-code:

```
template = "START_*_hello_*.pdf"
while true:
      while "file having template does not exist":
            time.sleep(1)

      found_file = get_existing_file
      file_processing(found_file)
```

The **os.path.exists(file_path)** function needs the entire filename. How could I used a filename containing the * jolly character?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for the [`glob` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `glob` module you could write something like this:

```
import glob

template = "START_*_hello_*.pdf"

while True:
    files = glob.glob(template)
    if not files:
        # no file matching template exists. Try again later.
        time.sleep(1)
        continue
    # Process all existing files
    for file in files:
        file_processing(file)
```

Comment: It is the way I was looking for. I think you missed a while loop. First while means "forever", second while means "until you find a file"

Comment: @Fab Ah, so you want to continuously process all existing files (even the ones you have already processed)?

Comment: Yes, several files having the same template could be pushed into the directory over time. Processed files will be deleted

Comment: @Fab There you go, no additional loop needed.